# Changing a static variable with a static method

Tags: java, variables, static

I'm trying to change a private static variable with via a static method and BlueJ says that I can't because the variable I'm trying to change (which is declared as static) is non-static:

```
public class Playerinfo {
    private static String name = ""; //Stores the name of the 'player'
    public static void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The variable is called name and the method is called setname. I know that I can do this:

```
Playerinfo.name = (insert variable here)
```

I don't like the above because I wish to have the name variable in Playerinfo declared as private as not to be meddled with by other classes that easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `this` inside a static method.

Your best bet is to rename the parameter of the method:

```
public class Playerinfo {
    private static String name = ""; //Stores the name of the 'player'
    public static void setname(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to a class instance, which is illegal in a static method. Either rename your parameter and do `name = param;`, or refer to it by class: `Playerinfo.name = name;`. Either way, it won't affect visibility to other classes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand name doesn't need to be static.Each PlayerInfo object must have its own name so remove static from both name and setname

```
public class Playerinfo{
    private  String name = ""; //Stores the name of the 'player'
    public void setname(String newName){
        this.name = newName;
}
```

Comment: I only plan to have Playerinfo as a reference class not as an object so that's why I'm using static variables and methods.